# getApplicationContext or get Context when setting up PnedingIntent

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Which context should be used with PendintIntent when setting alarms? ApplicationContext or activity Context?

Does it even matter? (performance and memory-wise) Is there any difference which one to use when setting alarms?

**More details**: I read somewhere that when you hold a reference to an activity's context, the activity never gets cleaned by Garbage Collector. So if I want to set 5 alarms daily and each of them has it's own context, wouldn't that cause leaking in memory if I pass in the activity context? Because the reference to the context never gets cleaned as the alarms are always in use.
what is the best practice (context-wise) to use the lowest memory?

here is how I create a PendingIntent already:

```
 public static void setAlarm(Context context, Activity activity){

    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    
    Calendar time = getTime();

    //set Alarm for different API levels
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
    }
    else{
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `context` in `PendingIntent` is used to start an object of a `class`. So I don't believe that it makes a difference to use any kind of `context` because as soon as the `class` in `PendingIntent` is launched, `context` object will be collected by Garbage collector.

Of course there are cases where `context` is preserved for further uses. But having multiple alarms each with one `context` doesn't seem to cause the memory problem. Note that by calling `getContext()` we use a `context`, and we don't create it. This means that there is just one more `pointer` to the `context` object which is a fairly expensive `object`. The `object` itself lives its own cycle regardless of what you use it for, unless you preserve it as a `Field` in a `class` or in a long running process.

Comment: What activity it starts when you use getApplicationContext then?! Besides, still the issue I stated is there. Everytime you create the context, you take some memory

Comment: I edited my answer. As mentioned before, you don't create a context, you just use it. So there is no reason to be concerned about the memory in your case @Keivan.k

Comment: Well as my operation is being processed in the background(the app is closed) then normally the context will be cleared. But now that I am holding a reference to it, it can't be cleaned bu Garbage collector right?

Comment: about the thing you said about the intention of context, well there actually to contexts, one context is included in the intent and one in the pending intent. the one in the intent is used to start an object of a class, but what about the one in the pending intent?

Comment: The one in PendingIntent is used to call `context.startActivity()`, `context.startService()`,... .

Comment: OK then the context object should live somewhere right? that means there is a context object somewhere in the memory

Comment: Yes, and you are not responsible for it. The system garbage collects the `context` object at proper time.

Comment: I understand and that is why I am asking this questions, because if I just keep holding reference to objects, then the garbage collector can not remove them and that will cause memory leaks. Or it may cause the app to crash